# Search each word in textbox from textfile and add to datatable

Tags: vb.net

I need search words from list of text files and each word is separated by space or semicolon in a textbox. Add rows to a datatable and display them to a datagrid. Problem is only the last word is displayed on the table. Thanks in advance.

```
    Sub test(ByVal strtofind As String)
    Dim tmp2Table As DataTable = New DataTable

    tmp2Table.Columns.Add("SN", GetType(String))
    tmp2Table.Columns.Add("Dataset", GetType(String))
    tmp2Table.Columns.Add("Param", GetType(String))
    tmp2Table.Columns.Add("Value", GetType(String))

    Dim strTemp() As String
    Dim lines() As String
    Dim strline As String = ""

    Dim fileList = Directory.GetFiles("C:\Users\sterc\Desktop\Traceview\Complete\", "*.txt", False)
    Dim sb = New StringBuilder()
    Dim result As String = String.Empty
    Dim value As String = String.Empty
    Dim s As String = txtParamSearch.Text
    Dim str As String = ""
    Dim strdataset As String = ""
    Dim strParam As String = ""
    Dim strParamResult As String = ""
    Dim strSN As String = ""

    For Each fileName In fileList
        lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
        Dim intTotalLines As Integer = lines.Length
        ' Split string based on spaces.
        For intCounter = 1 To intTotalLines - 1
            strline = lines(intCounter)
            If (Regex.IsMatch(strline, "----- Test_") And Regex.IsMatch(strline, ", Started At ")) Then

                strTemp = strline.Split(" ")
                strdataset = strTemp(3).TrimEnd(",")
            End If
            If Regex.IsMatch(strline, "Reported module serial number:") Then
                strTemp = Regex.Split(strline, ": ")
                strSN = strTemp(1)
            End If
            Dim strParamtofind As String = "\b" & strtofind & "\b\s+(\w+)"

            For Each a As Match In Regex.Matches(strline, strParamtofind, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

                tmp2Table.Rows.Add(strSN, strdataset, a.Groups(0).Value, a.Groups(1).Value)

            Next

        Next

    Next
    DataGridView1.DataSource = tmp2Table

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub strArr()

    Dim s As String = txtParamSearch.Text
    Dim str As String = ""

    Dim words As String() = s.Split(New [Char]() {";"c})

    Dim word As String
    For Each word In words
        test(word)
    Next

End Sub
```

[image]

Another thing is displays the whole number or round off. Suppose like below figure.(with decimal point)

[image]

---

I need to search data/s from a text file, each file contains below line. Then under it are the datas I might be listed on the textbox to find.
Let's say from the textbox I need to find,

- SOA_MinCurrent_EDATA;
- Isoa_OPSL_initial

Each of the two listed, will search each text file listed under a folder. Then display them line by line. Just like above screenshot. The problem is only the string search is displayed and numbers are round off.

---

```
 Testing tune_rf_pwr-rm-f-tpt ----- Test_TxLaserPwrTune, Started At   9/16/2017 5:25:00 PM
 more lines here....
 ...................
 ---tx_laser_pwr_tune_Params    Isoa_OPSL,Isoa_OPSH,laser_power_sp
 ---laser_power_target  2.5
 ---laser_power_initial 2.45000004768372
 ---Isoa_OPSL_initial   2.67
 ---Isoa_OPSH_initial   2.67
 ---laser_power_sp_initial  2.67
 ---Isoa_OPSL   2.67
 ---Isoa_OPSH   2.67
 ---laser_power_sp  2.67
 ---laser_pwr_tune  2.45000004768372
 ---laser_power_target056   2.46
 ---SOA_MinCurrent_EDATA    23.7778471526403
 ---SOA_MinCurrent_Chan 22
 ---SOA_MaxCurrent_EDATA    45.1157734448841
 ---SOA_MaxCurrent_Chan 98
 ---SOA_Current_initial[056]    57.082
 ---SOA_Current_initial[022]    49.389
 ---SOA_Current_initial[098]    49.389
 ---laser_power 2.46
 ---SOA_Current056  57.082
 ---SOA_Current022  49.389
 ---SOA_Current098  68.437
 ---tune_rf_sp_data:tx_laser_pwr_tune_Params    Isoa_OPSL,Isoa_OPSH,laser_power_sp
 ---tune_rf_sp_data:laser_power_target  2.5
 ---tune_rf_sp_data:laser_power_initial 2.45000004768372
 ---tune_rf_sp_data:Isoa_OPSL_initial   2.67
 ---tune_rf_sp_data:Isoa_OPSH_initial   2.67
 ---tune_rf_sp_data:laser_power_sp_initial  2.67
 ---tune_rf_sp_data:Isoa_OPSL   2.67
 ---tune_rf_sp_data:Isoa_OPSH   2.67
 ---tune_rf_sp_data:laser_power_sp  2.67
 ---tune_rf_sp_data:laser_pwr_tune  2.45000004768372
 ---tune_rf_sp_data:laser_power_target056   2.46
 ---tune_rf_sp_data:SOA_MinCurrent_EDATA    23.7778471526403
 ---tune_rf_sp_data:SOA_MinCurrent_Chan 22
 ---tune_rf_sp_data:SOA_MaxCurrent_EDATA    45.1157734448841
 ---tune_rf_sp_data:SOA_MaxCurrent_Chan 98
 ---tune_rf_sp_data:SOA_Current_initial[056]    57.082
 ---tune_rf_sp_data:SOA_Current_initial[022]    49.389
 ---tune_rf_sp_data:SOA_Current_initial[098]    49.389
 ---tune_rf_sp_data:laser_power 2.46
 ---tune_rf_sp_data:SOA_Current056  57.082
 ---tune_rf_sp_data:SOA_Current022  49.389
 ---tune_rf_sp_data:SOA_Current098  68.437
```

Comment: Maybe, instead of using a string data type for words, try using a list(of string), and use a loop for handling each semi-colon split, add those to the list, and loop through the list for your data table rows

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused here if you provide more info I can help you.

You have multiple files, some of the files split the values for each columns with spaces and does not have any semicolon inside the file, and others split the values for each column with semicolons and does not have spaces inside the file correct?

If the previous question is true and each line in the file contains the info that will fill each row, then I will use:

```
Dim r as StreamReader as New StreamReader(FilePath)
Dim Line as String

Do While StreamReader.Peek() > -1 //Go through the file until EOF

Line = r.readline() //Read the line and put it into Line
If InStr(Line, " ") Then  //Search for spaces inside Line
//This file is separated by spaces, put the code to add to the table.
Else If InStr(Line, ";") Then //search for semicolons inside line.
//This file is separated by semicolons, put the code to add to the table.
End If

Loop
```

I hope this helps.  If no please provide us with a little more detail.

Comment: Hi Alvaro, I have added details.

Comment: Hi Alvaro, I have solved the issue by putting the datatable on button_click. Now works perfectly. Thanks for your time.